# What should the baseurl, url of the jekyll blog?

Tags: jekyll

I have my previous site on https://vchrombie.github.io/ and I want my blog to be hosted on https://vchrombie.github.io/blog

I have created a new repository https://github.com/vchrombie/blog for this.

This is my configurations in [_config.yml](https://github.com/vchrombie/blog/blob/gh-pages/_config.yml)

```
# Dependencies
markdown:         redcarpet
highlighter:      pygments
# Permalinks
permalink:        pretty

# Setup
title:            vchrombie
tagline:          'A Jekyll theme'
description:      'A brazen two-column <a href="http://jekyllrb.com" target="_blank">Jekyll</a> theme that pairs a prominent sidebar with uncomplicated content. Made by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo" target="_blank">@mdo</a>.'
url:              "http://vchrombie.github.io/blog"
baseurl:          

disqus_shortname: vchrombie
author:
  name:           'Venu'
  url:            https://vchrombie.github.io/
paginate:         10
plugins: [jekyll-paginate]    
# Custom vars
appname:          blog
version:          2.1.0
github:
  repo:           https://github.com/vchrombie/blog/
```

Everything is working fine in localhost but when I push the code to GitHub, I cannot actually load my blog.

What should I change to make my blog live?

Comment: You can see my blog at 
https://vchrombie.github.io/blog/

It is a plain HTML. But this actually works fine with the `jekyll serve`
What changes should I do?

Answer (score 4):

This setup will work :

```
url: http://vchrombie.github.io
baseurl: /blog
```